# How to distinguish a native HTMLElement from a created/custom one?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

Let's suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>My first menu</li>
      <li>My second menu</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<header>
<main>
  <section>
    <h2>My title</h2>
    <my-beautiful-text>My text</my-beautiful-text>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  Copyright © 2015
</footer>
```

While I'm looping all the elements, I'd like to know if the element (eg `nav`) is a native HTMLElement or it's a created one (eg `my-beautiful-text`).

I've already searched for it on Google and here, but had no lucky.

My tries were using the `constructor` and `instanceof`, and it works for some elements, like `span`, `div`, `input` etc, but it doesn't work for some components that do not overrides the `HTMLElement` prototype. Any guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag names with dashes are custom.

See spec http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/